# Storing settings on the database for a web app?

Tags: database

I'm developing an open-source web application (a helpdesk) where the users will download it and install. This application will have some settings like: title, colors, default e-mail, logs... (for example). This settings will be edited by the user on the admin panel because most of them will not understand how to do it in code.

My question is what is the best way to store this on a (MySQL) database model? And counting that this application will upgrade and add more "settings" to that settings table.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different ways to do this, and it depends on what you think the final needs will be.

There's nothing wrong with saving parameters in a dedicated table, each parameter/user/value on a separate row.  This is a fast way to set and get the information, and allows you to easily get access to reports by parameter and value and user, for example, what colors are the most popular.

If you are just using this for configuration, you can store the parameters as an XML or JSON string in a text/blob field.  This has the benefit of giving you a single load to get all of the parameter values.  Even more powerful, if your application already has default values for the parameters, you can easily extend the application without changing the database records.  For a large number of parameters, this reduces the number of DB calls to load up all the parameters.

Comment: The idea is not to have a value for user, it's general config of the application so it will not change. I've seen schemas with 1 row an column for each attribute, or row for each attribute. The idea of XML/JSON sound very good way to do it.